CSS Label in border with coloured bg
I'm trying to get this:

Issue is that I do not have a linear background.
I have this Background:

Is there a way to reach that result without having to set the background color to the label?
I know this method:
input {  
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 16px 0 10px;    
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 10px;
  background: white;
}

But like I said setting the background to a color is not the way since the background color is not linear.
I cannot use <fieldset>.
This is exactly what i have for the form:
    <div class="edit_apt_form ">
            {{form_start(form)}}
        <div class="edit_apt_form__left">
        <h2 class="heading-secondary heading-secondary--small">Dati Alloggio</h2>
        <hr class="separation_line">
    </div>
        <div class="edit_apt_form__right">
            <div class="edit_apt_form__right--field--row three__fields">
                         
 {{form_row(form.address.components.addressPrefix)}}
                                     
 {{form_row(form.address.components.addressName)}}
                                     
 {{form_row(form.address.components.number)}}
           </div>
   </div>

The only solution i have found is to use position: absolute
    .edit_apt_form__right label {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
    margin-left: 1.4rem;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    left: 9px;
}
    .edit_apt_form__right--field--row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}


Fieldset would be the best solution. Failing that, here is a reasonable solution.

Could you show us the relevant HTML/CSS as I am unclear what element it is that has that background (e.g. body or a parent container...) and is the background of the input itself to be white? I also didn't understand the CSS you have already given as the input border is set at none.

sorry u are right! the border is set to 1px solid. and the bg of the input is set to transparent. The image of the bg i've posted shows the bg of the body. the structure is: <div class="card><div class="card-body> 

Best if you could put the HTML into the question and mend the CSS.

Please put the relevant HTML into the question - you can find the HTML that has been generated by whatever system you are using by looking in your browser devtools inspect facility. And making a runnable snippet would be very helpful.
